# dc.js + make the chart dynamic based on the dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/hcfhds0a/1/)

What I am looking for is a way to handle more elements in the data array, which I am demonstrating in this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hcfhds0a/5/). You can see it does appear as well with the new data, that is the graph is not that legible.

**How can I make the size of the chart vary depending on the data array?**

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/hcfhds0a/6/) you can see setting the height to 600 makes it appear more legibale

```
spenderRowChart
    .width(250).height(600)
```

**But how do I make this dynamic based on the data array(dataset)?**

I understand it might not be a black and white answer but I would appreciate some pointers. I am currently doign some research [here](http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/28/responsive-charts-with-d3/) and [here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array length, example for approximately 30px bars:

```
  spenderRowChart
    .width(250).height(30*data1.length)
```

Comment: tks, i thought of that after posting the question. I initially though it might be more complicated.

Comment: `group.all().length` is probably more accurate